# python DELETE rows from mysql with REGEXP and mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, regex

Code setup according to examples found here:

```
 for ICAO_COUNTRY in ['GM','DA','DT']:
  table='aerodrome'
  query = 'delete from %s where code_icao regexp "%s[A-Z][A-Z]"'
  cursor.execute(query,(table,ICAO_COUNTRY))
```

gives for answer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/cleanup2", line 22, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query,(table,ICAO_COUNTRY))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 635, in cmd_query statement))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 553, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''aerodrome' where code_icao regexp "'GM'[A-Z][A-Z]"' at line 1
```

It seems to me that the single quotes get transferred to the MySql engine, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are automatically added since you are binding a parameter that is supposed to be a field, a table name, a value. But you can't use this syntax to make a string replacement, it is different from a basic formatted string with placeholders

You can solve the problem with:

```
for ICAO_COUNTRY in ['GM','DA','DT']:
  table='aerodrome'
  query = 'delete from %s where code_icao regexp \'' + ICAO_COUNTRY + '[A-Z][A-Z]\'' 
  cursor.execute(query, table)
```

Or you can change your query to

```
query = 'delete from %s where code_icao regexp concat(%s, \'[A-Z][A-Z]\')'
cursor.execute(query, (table,ICAO_COUNTRY))
```

Comment: Well, I really believed Python would not impose such inelegant coding. Better this than nothing, though. That is, if it would work, but alas it doesn't.

Comment: @Karlchen9: an other way is to use `CONCAT` in your query.

Comment: @Karlchen9: An other problem, if you use double quotes in your query, you must have ansi_quotes enable in MySQL. If it isn't the case, try to replace them with single quotes.